# Adding additional option values to the selectbox after they are typed in the input box

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help.

I have the following code below, which works well if only one single value is added into the select box after it has been typed out in the input box (hence, making it an editable selectbox), then if another value is typed out in the input box, the content of the select box is changed to the newly entered value.

I would like to modify the code below so as to allow additional typed in values to be added into the selectbox.

```
<html> 

<style> 

#list { 
    left: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetLeft); 
    width: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetWidth);  
    clip: expression("rect(2px auto 20px " + (this.previousSibling.offsetWidth - 20) + "px)"); 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
}
#text1 {
    border: 0;
    height: 18px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style> 

<script language="javascript"> 
function getval() {
var select = document.getElementById('list')

    document.getElementById('text1').value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text

}//end of function

var oNewOption = null;

function AddListItem(oInput) {

var oSelect = oInput.nextSibling;

if (oNewOption == null) {
oNewOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
oSelect.options.add(oNewOption);
}

oNewOption.text = oInput.value;
oNewOption.value = oInput.value;

}

</script> 
<body> 

<div id="wrapper">
<input id="text1" type="text" onkeyup="AddListItem(this)"><select id="list" onchange="getval()"> 
</select>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, I had to change onkeyup to onchange. So the option will only get added after the input element loses focus.

```
<html> 

<style> 

#list { 
    left: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetLeft); 
    width: expression(this.previousSibling.offsetWidth);  
    clip: expression("rect(2px auto 20px " + (this.previousSibling.offsetWidth - 20) + "px)"); 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
}
#text1 {
    border: 0;
    height: 18px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style> 

<script language="javascript"> 
function getval() {
var select = document.getElementById('list')

    document.getElementById('text1').value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text

}//end of function

var oNewOption = null;

function AddListItem(oInput) {

var oSelect = oInput.nextSibling;


oNewOption = document.createElement("OPTION");
oSelect.options.add(oNewOption);


oNewOption.text = oInput.value;
oNewOption.value = oInput.value;
oNewOption.selected = true;

}

</script> 
<body> 

<div id="wrapper">
<input id="text1" type="text" onchange="AddListItem(this)"><select id="list" onchange="getval()"> 
</select>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```